# Discord.py add roles from dropdown menu

Tags: python, discord.py

I currently have a dropdown with a list of colors which are the same as the roles i have in my server and was wondering if its possible to add a role based on which option is selected. I can get it to add a single role when any option is selected but don't know how to add one for each individual option and also make it so it removes the previous role that was selected but also doesnt remove all of the other roles the user may have.

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Dropdown(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):

        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label='Pomegranate', description='Your favourite colour is red', emoji=':Pomegranate:910060219420278844:'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Rose', description='Your favourite colour is green', emoji=':Rose:910060219013410818'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Apple', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Apple:910060219256672266'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Crimson', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Crimson:910060219390906398'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Apricot', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Apricot:910060218883395675'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Tangerine', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Tangerine:910060219474780210'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Giants Road', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':GiantsRoad:910060219348955206'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Cocoa', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Cocoa:910060219525107742'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Chiffon', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Chiffon:910060219286032384'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Lemon', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Lemon:910060219332198441'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Gold', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Gold:910060219239911456'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Brass', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Brass:910060219235700756'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Green Tea', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':GreenTea:910060219315400704'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Mint Leaves', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':MintLeaves:910060219126648884'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Apple Green', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':AppleGreen:910060219239915551'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Ivy', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Ivy:910060219294433280'),

        ]
        super().__init__(placeholder='Choose your role colour...', min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options)

    async def callback(self, ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your role colour is {self.values[0]}')


class Dropdown2(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label='Aero', description='Your favourite colour is red', emoji='Aero:910060219030179841'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Turquoise', description='Your favourite colour is green', emoji=':Turquoise:910060219294449694'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Sapphire', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Sapphire:910060219193770005'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Egyptian Blue', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':EgyptianBlue:910060219449622589'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Periwinkle', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Periwinkle:910060218963091477'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Ube', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Ube:910060219302826034'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Amethyst', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Amethyst:910060219340566528'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Violet', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Violet:910060219323797534'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Piggy', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Piggy:910060219147624499'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Carnation', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Carnation:910060219059544115'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Strawberry', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Strawberry:910060219365748746'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Paradise', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Paradise:910060219298615316'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Platinum', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Platinum:910060219382530068'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Chalice', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Chalice:910060219248308264'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Silver', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Silver:910060219084714075'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Smoke', description='Your favourite colour is blue', emoji=':Smoke:910060219378331648'),

        ]
        super().__init__(placeholder='Choose your role colour...', min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options)

    async def callback(self, ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your role colour is {self.values[0]}')

class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown())

class DropdownView2(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown2())

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('$'))

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('------')
    
    
bot = Bot()


@bot.command()
async def colour(ctx):
    """Sends a message with our dropdown containing colours"""
    view = DropdownView()
    view2 = DropdownView2()

    await ctx.send('Pick your role colour:', view=view)
    await ctx.send('Pick your role colour:', view=view2) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the previous role the user selected in a variable. Then use discord.py's `Member.remove_roles` and remove the previously selected role. Something like this:

```py
class Dropdown(ui.Select):
    ...
    def __init__(...):
        self.previous_role = None

    async def callback(self,ctx,interaction):
        ...
        if self.previous_role is not None:
            await ctx.author.remove_roles(self.previous_role)
```

(Note that everytime I wrote ... that is where some code is missing, not an Ellipsis)